# How to set up Angular

Tags: web-applications, angularjs, configuration

I am building a web app with Angular and have written some HTML, but the Angular isn't working. It's as if it's not being downloaded. So when I include a test angular expression in my html like {{1+2}} it is rendered exactly like that. Is there anything that I need to do besides include the following line in my HTML code?

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.6/angular.min.js"></script>
```

I'm sorry that this isn't the most interesting question, but I have been stuck without working Angular for a while, and I really can't figure out why. Thanks!

Comment: Strongly recommend that you take the Angular Phonecat tutorial found [here](http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial)

Comment: Thanks! I have done it actually--my problem was that I tried to name my module, like they did in the tutorial, but it wasn't being recognized by angular for some reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define the module and the controller. Look for `ng-app` and `ng-controller` in this Plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/jcLnWlg3Kw7i6QuCjrdK?p=preview

You can also take a look at the angularjs seed https://github.com/angular/angular-seed

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the type attribute, I've seen this cause problems before.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.6/angular.min.js"></script>
```

Also, definitely use F12 tools/firebug/etc.. to see if the script is actually loading when your document is loaded.

Comment: Thank you for reminding me that those tools exist :) they told me that Angular wasn't recognizing my ng-app tag, which fixed it!